# remove folder icon in jstree while using checkbox

Tags: jstree

How does one remove the folder icon in jstree whilst using the checkbox plugin?

```
$('#div').jstree({
        "ui": {
            "theme_name": "checkbox"
        },
        "theme" : { "icons": false },
        "json_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "type": "POST",
                "url": "@Url.Action("Tree")"
            }
        },
        "plugins": ["json_data", "checkbox", "ui", "themes"]
    });
```

This all works fine but it displays the checkbox icon as well as the folder icon.

Answer (score 81):

in the latest jstree version i.e. jstree-3, the themes option goes into the "core" object

```
"core": {
        "themes":{
            "icons":false
        }
    }
```

Comment: For other people : If you use this https://github.com/tristanm/jstree-rails, you must hide icons via css (display: none)

Answer (score 11):

Got it... Should have been "themes" : { "icons": false }